# How to custom alignment in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: alignment, sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

Well I'm using `Sublime Text 2` for a lot of tasks, included the creation of documents with `LaTeX`. I downloaded and installed the `alignment`package and works great when I want to align respect the `=` symbol. But in `LaTeX` I need to align also with respect to `&` and sometimes `%` but I don't understand where or how can I custom that. I read the documentation about that package [here](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/alignment), and now I see I must go to `Preferences > Package Settings > Alignment > Settings – User` but there the only I see is:

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai Bright.tmTheme",
    "font_size": 12.0,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage",
        "PyV8"
    ]
}
```

And I don't know what exactly should I add, and if it's before close the `{}` o later opening a new pair. Could someone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my mac you would need to look at `Alignment/Base File.sublime-settings`

```
// The mid-line characters to align in a multi-line selection, changing
// this to an empty array will disable mid-line alignment
"alignment_chars": ["="],
```

Add the characters you want to align on either to this file, or create a user settings file as you indicated.

```
"alignment_chars": ["=", "%", "&"],
```

The contents of the file you listed is actually your user system preferences, not the user settings file for Alignment.

Comment: Thanks!, now I see where to edit the file. I was wrong in the path.